# Multiple YouTube v2 API Calls Not Retrieving All Content

Tags: php, json, youtube-api, gdata-api, youtube-data-api

Okay, so I am using the YouTube v2 gdata API on a PHP server.

My attempt is to pull the top 100 most subscribed users (Which works) and then pull the top 50 videos for each user and place them neatly, in JSON format, into individual .txt files so that I may access them as needed. Here is what I have:

```
<?PHP

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://<EXAMPLE>.com/appData/?load=100&alt=json"),true);

foreach($data['entry'] as $entry){
    $ytUser = $entry['YouTuberName'];
    $ytURL = $entry['TransitionURL'];
    $ytUserString = str_replace(' ', '', $ytUser);

    $json_array = array();  

    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($ytURL . "/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=50&orderby=viewCount"),true);

    for($i=0;$i!=count($json['data']['items']);$i++){
        $item = $json['data']['items'][$i];
            $itemID = $item['id'];
            $numRatings = $item['ratingCount'];
            $tmp_json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$itemID."?v=2&alt=json"),true);
            $tmp_arr['id'] = $item['id'];
            $tmp_arr['uploaded'] = $item['uploaded'];
            $tmp_arr['title'] = $item['title'];
            $tmp_arr['thumbnail'] = $item['thumbnail']['hqDefault'];
            $tmp_arr['mplayer'] = $item['player']['mobile'];
            $tmp_arr['dplayer'] = $item['player']['default'];
            $tmp_arr['duration'] = $item['duration'];
            $tmp_arr['likes'] = $item['likeCount'];
            $tmp_arr['dislikes'] = (string)($numRatings - (int)$tmp_arr['likes']);
            $tmp_arr['views'] = $item['viewCount'];
            $tmp_arr['comments'] = $item['commentCount'];
            $tmp_arr['desc'] = $tmp_json['entry']['media$group']['media$description']['$t'];

            array_push($json_array,$tmp_arr);           
    }

    $json_arr = json_encode($json_array);
    $contents = "{\"entry\":" . $json_arr . "}";
    $filename = "/home/<USERNAME>/public_html/appData/popular/" . $ytUserString . ".txt";
    file_put_contents((string)$filename, $contents);
}
?>
```

The code is very simple, and it is sort of working, but after the 3rd user in the list no more data is pulled. So I have 63 .txt files, but only 3 of them have JSON data in them and the other 60 only have NULL arrays.

THE FIRST LINK I HAVE SET AS $data IS THE JSON I SET UP FROM THE FIRST API CALL THAT GATHERS THE MOST SUBSCRIBED YOUTUBERS.